# Fetch API - GET request with status 200 returning an empty body

Tags: javascript, c#, get, frontend, fetch

I got a really weird problem. This javascript code is supposed to fetch an object from the back-end with a GET-request. The header I receive has status 200, but the body seems to be empty.

```js
function GetAssignment() {
    assignment = fetch(GetAssignmentURL,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            }
            else
            {
                throw `error with status ${response.status}`;
            }
        })
        
        .catch((exception) => {
            console.log(exception);
        }); 
}
```

Response:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3pfo.png

Now, I tried the same thing with Postman, and it works just fine here. (I've checked the URL to call the back-end and it's totally the same in Postman as in Javascript, so the error doesn't lie there.) 
Result: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Pnm.png

So, I'm wondering what's wrong with my Javascript code. I debugged the back-end, and when I'm calling with Javascript it does return an object like how it should. I've always done GET-requests this way, but now all of a sudden, the response body is being obstructed in the front-end of my application.

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing in the code you've shown is actually *using* the body. You're logging `response` before you tell it to read the body, and your `assignment` variable just has the promise from `fetch`, it doesn't try to do anything with it.

To see the body, you need to look at the fulfillment value of the promise from `json` (which will do two things: 1. read the body, and 2. parse it from JSON).

For instance:

```
function GetAssignment() {
    fetch(GetAssignmentURL,                 // *** No `assignment =` on this line
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {   // *** This can be just `if (response.ok) {`
                console.log(response);      // *** This is premature
                return response.json();
            }
            else
            {
                throw `error with status ${response.status}`;
            }
        })
        .then(assignment => {               // ***
            // ...use `assignment` here...  // ***
        })                                  // ***
        .catch((exception) => {
            console.log(exception);
        }); 
}
```

**But:** If the goal is to communicate `assignment` to the code calling the function, you need to return the promise chain, like this:

```
function GetAssignment() {
    return fetch(GetAssignmentURL,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {   // *** This can be just `if (response.ok) {`
                console.log(response);      // *** This is premature
                return response.json();
            }
            else
            {
                throw `error with status ${response.status}`;
            }
        });
}
```

Code using it would use it like this:

```
GetAssignment()
.then(assignment => {
    // ...use `assignment` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // handle/report error
});
```

---

Side note: If `GetAssignment` isn't meant to be called with `new`, the overwhelmingly-common convention in JavaScript is that it would start with a lowercase letter: `getAssignment`.

---

And just to put it out there, since ES2018 was a couple of years ago now, in modern environments (or if you're transpiling) you can use `async` functions, which make it possible to write your logic without worrying as much about timing. `async` functions return promises, and let you use `await` to pause your logic while waiting for a promise to settle:

```
async function getAssignment() {
    const response = await fetch(GetAssignmentURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            
        }
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw `error with status ${response.status}`;
    }
    return response.json();
}
```

In the above, the call to `fetch` happens synchronously, but then the function suspends itself waiting for the result and returns a promise. The promise it returns will settle based on what happens to the promise(s) it `await`s. Eventually, all being well, its promise is fulfilled with the value you `return` (or in the case of the above, the fulfillment value `response.json()` provides when it settles).

You'd use it like this (inside another `async` function):

```
const assignment = await getAssignment();
// ...use `assignment` here...
```

(If there's an error, the `async` function the code above is in will reject the promise)

Comment: @MathiasGielen - Glad that helped. Just beware of the timing: `GetAssignment` returns **before** the `fetch` operation completes. I only mention it because in the earlier comment you removed, it seemed like you might have not realized that. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah, that's another thing...
When the function hits the response.json(), it stops and jumps to the part where I declare assignment and do things with its properties. Of course, the exception says that I can't do things with a null value. *After* that, it reaches the .then, where my variable receives the value of the response body, but by then it's too late. How can I assign the response body to my variable before the function returns?

Comment: @MathiasGielen - You literally can't, you have to do it as above. More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call `async` functions provide a (much) better syntax for it, though.

Comment: I got it working. Pasted almost the entirety of my code within the .then. 
With an if-function, I check if assignment is null or not. If so: it will skip everything and continue with code outside of the function that doesn't make the rest crash. In time, the .then will be called again, this time with a value, so the code will be executed. :-)